# Ajax response not displaying anything in view file (Yii)

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, yii

I have a file ( _gen.php) that is in my view that sends selected data to the controller file for verification:

```
   $('#validate').on('click',function(){
        var data = []; // data container
        // collect all the checked checkboxes and their associated attributes
        $("table#subsection_table input[type='checkbox']:checked").each(function(){
            data.push({
                section : $(this).data('sectionid'),
                subsection : $(this).val(),
                year : $(this).data('year')


           })
       });
        // JSON it so that it can be passed via Ajax call to a php page
        var data = JSON.stringify(data);


        $.ajax({
            url : "<?php echo Yii::app()->createAbsoluteUrl("scheduler/ScheduleValidation"); ?>",
            type: "POST",
            data : "myData=" + data,
            success : function(data)
            {
                $("#ajax-results").html(data);
                $("#ajax-results").dialog({ width: 500, height: 500})
            },
            error: function()
            {
                alert("there was an error")
            }
        })
        console.log(JSON.stringify(data));

        $('#dialog').html(data).dialog({ width: 500, heigh: 500});
    });
```

Now #ajax-result is the id of one of my div tag after my button ( last thing displayed on the page).

As for the controller function, I do know it handles the data fine and the sql call correctly ( I made sure of it). However when I call renderPartial it will call my _ajax.php file correctly but it will only displayed it in an alert box, not to the #ajax-result tag. The controller function:

```
  public function actionScheduleValidation()
{
    print_r("in ajax");
    $post_data = $_POST['myData'];
    $decodedData = json_decode($post_data, true);
    //$course = [[[]]];
    $course=[];
    $counter = 0;
    //Save the years associated to sections chosen

    foreach ($decodedData as $key) {
        $tutOrLab = null;
        $lec = null;
        $currentYear = null;
        foreach ($key as $id => $number) {
            if ($id == 'year') {
                $currentYear = $number;
            } elseif ($id == 'subsection') {
                $tutOrLab = Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
                    ->select('courseID,kind,days,start_time,end_time,semester')
                    ->from($id)
                    ->where('id=' . $number)
                    ->queryRow();
            } else
                $lec = Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
                    ->select('courseID,kind,days,start_time,end_time,semester')
                    ->from($id)
                    ->where('id=' . $number)
                    ->queryRow();

        }
        print_r(gettype($lec['start_time']));
        $lecture = new Lecture($lec['courseID'],$lec['kind'],$lec['days'],$lec['start_time'],$lec['end_time'],$lec['semester'],$currentYear);
        print_r(gettype($lecture->getStartTime()));
        // WILL ACTUALLY DISPLAY SOMETHING
        $tutorial = new TutorialAndLab($tutOrLab['courseID'],$tutOrLab['kind'],$tutOrLab['days'],$tutOrLab['start_time'],$tutOrLab['end_time'],$tutOrLab['semester'],$currentYear);
        $course[$counter] = new CourseObj($lecture,$tutorial);
        $counter++;

    }

    $courseYear1Fall = [];
    $courseYear1Winter = [];
    $courseYear2Fall = [];
    $courseYear2Winter = [];
    $courseYear3Fall = [];
    $courseYear3Winter = [];
    $courseYear4Fall = [];
    $courseYear4Winter = [];
    if($course != null) {
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($course); $i++) {
            if ($course[$i]->getLecture()->getYear() == '1') {
                if ($course[$i]->getLecture()->getSemester() == 'F') {

                    array_push($courseYear1Fall, $course[$i]);

                } elseif ($course[$i]->getLecture()->getSemester() == 'W') {

                    array_push($courseYear1Winter, $course[$i]);
                }
            } elseif ($course[$i]->getLecture()->getYear() == '2') {

                if ($course[$i]->getLecture()->getSemester() == 'F') {

                    array_push($courseYear2Fall, $course[$i]);

                } elseif ($course[$i]->getLecture()->getSemester() == 'W')

                    array_push($courseYear2Winter, $course[$i]);

            } elseif ($course[$i]->getLecture()->getYear() == '3') {
                if ($course[$i]->getLecture()->getSemester() == 'F') {

                    array_push($courseYear3Fall, $course[$i]);

                } elseif ($course[$i]->getLecture()->getSemester() == 'W') {

                    array_push($courseYear3Winter, $course[$i]);

                }

            } elseif ($course[$i]->getLecture()->getYear() == '4') {

                if ($course[$i]->getLecture()->getSemester() == 'F') {

                    array_push($courseYear4Fall, $course[$i]);

                } elseif ($course[$i]->getLecture()->getSemester() == 'W') {

                    array_push($courseYear4Winter, $course[$i]);
                }
            }
        }
        $counter2=0;
        $errorArr = [];
        if($courseYear1Fall != null){
            $fallErr = verification($courseYear1Fall);
            $errorArr[$counter2] = $fallErr;
            $counter2++;
        }
        elseif($courseYear1Winter != null) {
            $winterErr = verification($courseYear1Winter);
            $errorArr[$counter2] = $winterErr;
            $counter2++;
        }
        if($courseYear2Fall != null) {
            $fallErr  = verification($courseYear2Fall);
            $errorArr[$counter2] = $fallErr;
            $counter2++;
        }
        if($courseYear2Winter != null) {
            $winterErr = verification($courseYear3Fall);
            $errorArr[$counter2] = $winterErr;
            $counter2++;
        }
        if($courseYear3Winter != null) {
            $fallErr = verification($courseYear3Fall);
            $errorArr[$counter2] = $fallErr;
            $counter2++;
        }
        if($courseYear3Fall != null) {
            $winterErr = verification($courseYear3Winter);
            $errorArr[$counter2] = $winterErr;
            $counter2++;

        }
        if($courseYear4Fall != null) {
            $fallErr = verification($courseYear4Fall);
            $errorArr[$counter2] = $fallErr;
            $counter2++;
        }
        if($courseYear4Winter != null) {
            $winterErr = verification($courseYear4Winter);
            $errorArr[$counter2] = $winterErr;
        }

        $this->renderPartial('_ajax', array(
                'data' => $errorArr,
            )
        );
    }
```

Any idea on how to append it to my original (_gen.php) html code?

Answer (score 0):

Your ajax call is missing semi-colon.

And probably as a good practise you should not be naming both request and response variable "data".